# Toggling selected states between multiple objects using ID from .map()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm attempting to toggle a selected/not-selected state for clickable cards being rendered using a `.map()`. I've found an example of the desired outcome I'd like to recreate, but haven't been successful at recreating it for the project I'm working on: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-khorana-d2hku?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:258-502

I'd like to use `eligiblePayee.id` as the unique identifier when selecting between the objects within the `eligiblePayees` array being passed since there could be 1 or more selected at once just like in the Code Sandbox example linked above.

Here's what I have so far and can get one Card component to be selected when using a simple useState() using [toggle, setToggle], but not multiple at a time.

```
const { currentStep, setCurrentStep } = useWithdrawal()
const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    const nextState = clicks.map(click => {
        if (click.id == eligiblePayeeId) {
          return setToggle(!toggle);
        }
        return { ...eligiblePayee, clicked: !eligiblePayee.clicked };
    });
    setClicks(nextState);
}, []);

const handleContinue = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('toggle value onClick: ', toggle);

    if(toggle === false) {
       // console.log('toggle value onClick: ', toggle);
        setFormError(true);
    }

    if(toggle === true) {
        return setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
    }
}, []);
```

```
{eligiblePayees.map(eligiblePayee => (
    <Card
        name={eligiblePayee.name}
        tags={eligiblePayee.tags}
        key={eligiblePayee.id}
        onClick={() => handleClick(eligiblePayee.id)}
    />
))}
<div>
    {formError && (
        <AssistiveText
            iconOverride={<ErrorIcon width={16} height={16} />}
            variant={AssistiveTextVariant.Error}
            text={t('withdrawals.payee.incompleteForm')}
        ></AssistiveText>
    )}
</div>

<div>
    <NavigationButtons handleContinue={handleContinue} />
</div>
```